# store the value to array, and select array intersected

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, intersect

1.I would like to store the array value to this three variable, and take the intersected value of it, but it did not work!

```
$report =array();
$report1 =array();
$report2 =array();
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($r_query)){
   echo 'Primary first State:' .$row['user_id'].'<br>';
    $report[]=array(
         'id'=>$row['user_id']);
}

while ($rowa=mysql_fetch_array($r_querya)){
   echo 'Primary second State:  ' .$rowa['user_id'].'<br>'; 
 $report1[]=array(
         'id'=>$rowa['user_id']);
}
while ($rowb=mysql_fetch_array($r_queryb)){
   echo 'Primary third State:  ' .$rowb['user_id'].'<br>';  
 $report2[]=array(
         'id'=>$rowb['user_id']);
}
echo var_dump($report);
   $result = array_intersect($report,$report1,$report2);
   echo 'intersect State:  ' .$result;
}
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: "Did not work" is not a diagnostic we can help you with. Do you have any errors to report? What query are you running? Are you even checking for errors when making SQL calls?

Comment: echo var_dump($report); The 3 array store the value like this     array(2) {
[0]=>
string(1) “5”
[1]=>
string(1) “7”
} but the intersect only output 'Array'!

Answer (score 0):

The result of an array_intersect is an array itself, thus replace the last line of code with something like:

```
echo 'intersect State:  ' . PHP_EOL;
var_dump($result);
```

In addition:

```
echo var_dump($report);
```

doesn't make much sense, use only the latter (var_dump) for arrays... .

Comment: Yes, it output the intersect value! thank you so much.  In addition,     can I directly use this variable to here
//Country output
$sqli = "SELECT meta_value FROM search WHERE user_id LIKE '%".$result."%' and meta_key='pmpro_bcountry'"; 
$r_queryi = mysql_query($sqli);

Comment: //Country output
$sqli = "SELECT meta_value FROM search WHERE user_id LIKE '%".$result."%' and meta_key='pmpro_bcountry'"; 
$r_queryi = mysql_query($sqli); 

while($a=mysql_fetch_array($r_queryi)){
echo '<br>County: '.$a[meta_value];
}

Comment: If your result returns an array of user_id -s you can accomplish it by: `$search_list = '(' . explode(',',$result) . ')'` and placing that in your sql like: `... WHERE user_id IN " . $search_list`;

Comment: The result is like this: @saulnier    array(1) {
[0]=>
array(2) {
[0]=>
string(1) “5”
[1]=>
string(1) “7”
}
}

Comment: This is the error warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in

Comment: Sorry, I meant `implode`

Comment: If this helped you, please indicate this as the answer. Thank you.

Comment: yes, I fix it, by changing the code: $result = array_values(array_intersect($report1,$report2,$report));